# Add Progress Bar to Jquery and PHP iFrame Uploader

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

How would you go about adding functionality to display a progress for the files that are uploaded via jQuery and PHP?

I currently have the following code. Ideally, I would like to display an image progress bar, that increased in size using CSS, and the upload completes.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#formsubmit").click(function () {

var iframe = $('<iframe name="postiframe" scr="http://www.google.co.uk" id="postiframe" style="display: none" />');

$("body").append(iframe);

var form = $('#theuploadform');
form.attr("action", "ddd.php");
form.attr("method", "post");
form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
form.attr("target", "postiframe");
form.attr("file", $('#userfile').val());
form.submit();

$("#postiframe").load(function () {
    iframeContents = $("#postiframe")[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    $("#textarea").html(iframeContents);
});

return false;

});

});
</script>

<form id="theuploadform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="123" />
<input id="userfile" name="userfile[]" size="50" type="file" multiple />
<input id="formsubmit" type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>

<div id="textarea"></div>
```

Cheers ;)

Comment: `[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML` ..? [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Answer (score 0):

You can only add a progress bar if you do it with ajax but the ajax file upload is not supported in IE and old FF versions.

So you'll need to use iframes without progress bar if it isn't supported. That's why many people had made nice workarounds for that. Some names of uploader plugins for jQuery are listed [here](http://micha.favor.org/mfuploader/).

You can also do it by yourself without a plugin but you can't use the jQuery ajax function because since jQuery 1.5.1 it doesn't give you the ability to access the native XHR object.